# Disable Adobe Air authentication dialog

Tags: javascript, authentication, air

I'm building an Adobe Air app that interacts with a third party service using HTTP Basic auth for it's authentication. I'd like to handle the login process completely in my own code. I'm using jQuery to handle the ajax.

The issue is that when the user enters bad credentials Air pops up an authentication dialog box before my javascript even gets notified of the 401.

I've read that there are two attributes I can mess with:

- window.htmlLoader.authenticate
- air.URLRequestDefaults.authenticate

Setting the URLRequestDefaults.authenticate to false seems to have no effect, which makes sense since I'm not using URLRequest. Setting the htmlLoader.authenticate definitely disables the dialog box from popping up, but every request is now returned as a 401.

Is there a way to prevent this dialog from popping up and letting my js handle the authentication?

Comment: Hi Matt,

I'm facing the same problem right now, did you find any solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I find the following code rather helpful when I'm forced to work with AIR, which in Britain is rather too often for comfort...

```
//The answer to life the universe and everything??
flash.net.URLRequestDefaults.authenticate = false;
flash.net.URLRequestDefaults.cacheResponse = false;
```

Now you will need to handle the authentication yourself or no cigar!